# Best way to iterate through a JSON object to create a ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I'm getting a [FullContact API](https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/) response in the form of a JSON object with some nested arrays that contain a set of contact details. I'd like to create an object in my Rails app controller that holds whatever information comes in the response. I'm trying to do this using a code like bellow (note that the gem I'm using allows accessing the object with dot notation):

```
@automatic_profile = AutomaticProfile.new(
  profile_id: @profile.id,
  first_name: @intel.contact_info.full_name,
  email: @profile.email,
  gender: @intel.demographics.gender,
  city: @intel.demographics.location_deduced.city.name,
  skype: @intel.contact_info.chats.select { |slot| slot.client == "skype" }[0].handle),
  organization_1: @intel.organizations[0].name if @intel.organizations,
  # other similar lines for other organizations
  twitter: (@intel.social_profiles.select { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }[0].url if @intel.social_profiles),
  twitter_followers: (@intel.social_profiles.select { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }[0].followers.to_i) if @intel.social_profiles,
  twitter_following: (@intel.social_profiles.select { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }[0].following.to_i if @intel.social_profiles),
  # other similar lines for other social profiles
)
```

I have two issues with this code:

1. The Json object won't always have all information required to populate some hash keys thus raising an exception when, for example, calling an index in an array that doesn't exist.

I've tried adding an if statement in each line like this:

```
twitter: (@intel.social_profiles.select { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }[0].url if @intel.social_profiles),
```

but it's not DRY and I'm so confused with the use of parenthesis that I'm raising additional exceptions.

2. In order to set the correct value to my keys I'm using the slot method to find the specific data I'm looking for.  This as well seems verbose and not much practical.

Could you advice on the best practice when it comes to create an object with data from big Json with nested array responses and advise on how could I solve this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.first`, `.try`. (and `.dig` if you're on ruby 2.3) to avoid exceptions when accessing them.

`.try` will just return nil if it can't be found. For example:

```
{ a: 2 }.try(:b) # returns nil
```

`.dig` is like `.try`, but it can go multiple levels so this might be useful for deeply nested ones.

```
[['a'], ['a','b']].dig(0, 1) # first element, then second element - nil
[['a'], ['a','b']].dig(1, 1) # second, then second again - 'b'

{ a: [1, 2] }.dig(:a, 0) # 1
{ a: [1, 2] }.dig(:a, 2) # nil

foo = OpenStruct.new
foo.bar = "foobar"
{ b: foo }.dig(:b, :bar) # 'foobar'

@intel.dig(:contact_info, :full_name)
@intel.dig(:organizations, :first, :name)
```

For the last part, you can also refactor it in this way:

```
def twitter_profile
  return unless @intel.social_profiles.present?
  @intel.social_profiles.find { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }
end

twitter: twitter_profile.try(:url),
twitter_followers: twitter_profile.try(:followers).to_i,
twitter_followings: twitter_profile.try(:followings).to_i,
```

`twitter_profile` could be a private method in the controller. If you find that you start to have too many of these, you could have a service object for the creation of a profile.

```
class ProfileCreatorService
  def initialize(intel)
    @intel = intel
  end

  def perform
    AutomaticProfile.new(...)
  end

  private 

  def twitter_profile
    return unless @intel.social_profiles.present?
    @intel.social_profiles.find { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }
  end

  ..
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ho. It looks that this is a much sensible approach. Let me try it and go back to you. 
One more thing though that method twitter_profile that you suggested where should it be set up. I am confused as there's no model Intel and it couldn't be an instance method of the Profile model as I haven't created  the object yet. Could you advise further?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like the code below added in application_record.rb

`  def twitter_profile
    return unless self.social_profiles
    self.social_profiles.select { |slot| slot.type_name == "Twitter" }.first
  end`

Comment: `return unless @intel.social_profiles.present?` would be better (if `social_profiles` is an empty array, then it will always be truthy). Also, doing `[].select { |el| el.some_cond? }.first` can be changed to `[].find { |el| el.some_cond? }` so will stop at the first truthy occurence and not execute the block for each array's element.

Comment: @andrew It could be just a private method in the controller. Or if it becomes too much there, you could create a service object that hides all these creation logic away from the controller. So you might have like ProfileCreator.new(@intel).perform (and this returns a profile)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, Ho. Thanks both for your very useful advice. It make sense now